# Rendering MySQL query with NodeJS and EJS

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, ejs

My aim would be to put my data from a MySQL query into an HTML table. However, I have the following output:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

from this simple `ejs` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
  <table>
  <% data.forEach(function(ind){ %>
    <li><%= data %></li>
  <% }) %>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

which takes the data from

```
  pool.query(query, function select(error, results, fields) {
    var temp = "";
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      pool.end();
    }
    res.render('index.html',{data:results, error:null});
    //pool.end();
  });
```

I do not know what is wong within my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
  <% data.forEach(function(ind){ %>
    <li><%= JSON.stringify(ind) %></li>
  <% }) %>
```